# Copying jar from local Maven repository

Tags: shell, maven, scripting, repository

I'm working on a sort of deployment script for a Java project using Python/shell. The script currently can copy jars either from a Sonatype Nexus repository or from the project's target folder. The remote/Nexus setup seems all good, but I'm interested in instead copying from the local maven repository because allows me to always know the location of the jar regardless of where the project is installed.

I guess my question is: Am I overlooking anything by just copying the first jar from the folder `~/.m2/repository/{groupid}/{artifactid}/{version}`? Or is this totally a good way to go about this?

Comment: how do you acquire the location of the local repository? By reading `settings.xml` ?

Comment: I assumed so far that it's always at ~/.m2/repository but I can surely read it from there. I'm mostly concerned about the structure of the repository once I've found it

Comment: I would like to know what is the "big picture" behind your question. Do you want to build a distribution which includes stuff like shell scripts and a directory structure beside the jar. Did you consider using the maven-assembly-plugin?

Comment: Well the ultimate product is much more than just the jar. The jars in the repository are actually plugins which are deployed to a remote server and the deployment script is very complex because the plugins are just one small aspect of the final product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `groupId` consists of more than one part, for example `org.apache.httpcomponents` , then the folder structure reflects this: `org/apache/httpcomponents/...`

[image]

There may exist more than one jar file inside the version directory.

Comment: I see now. I was indeed interested if there were caveats like whether there could be multiple jars inside the folder. I should be safe with just making sure not to copy a jar which ends with "-javadoc.jar" or "-sources.jar". And again, this local "hack" is just for fast testing. The script will grab releases with Nexus' API for a more "real" deployment :)